# Add precision by one to the BigDecimal number?

Tags: java

I have a requirement as below.

I have  a number of BigDecimal type : 100

```
i need a method which will take input(100 here) and gives output as 100.1
if 100.1 is passed it should return 100.2
if 100.2 is passed it should return 100.3....etc
```

Is there any simplest solution?

Thanks!

Comment: does it always add .1 to any number? if you pass 100.01 would it return 100.02 or 100.11?

Comment: it should return 100.02 not 100.11. Thanks!

Comment: what should be result for 100.012 100.022 or 100.013?

Comment: probably you need to do string manipulation to calculate the precision and then add the number/(10^precision)

Comment: What should it do when passed 100.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>You can rescale it, add 1, and then scale it back.</del>
This can be simplified, as @PeterLawrey suggests, to just add `BigDecimal.ONE.scaleByPowerOfTen(-scale)`.

```
public static BigDecimal increaseBy1(BigDecimal value) {
    int scale = value.scale();
    return value.add(BigDecimal.ONE.scaleByPowerOfTen(-scale));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(increaseBy1(new BigDecimal("100.012")));
    System.out.println(increaseBy1(new BigDecimal("100.01")));
    System.out.println(increaseBy1(new BigDecimal("100.1")));
    System.out.println(increaseBy1(new BigDecimal("100")));
}
```

prints

```
100.013
100.02
100.2
101
```

If you want `100` to become `100.1`, change the first line to

```
int scale = Math.max(1, value.scale());
```

Comment: or you could add `BigDecimal.ONE.scaleByPowerOfTen(-scale)`

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Yes, sounds much better. Editing.

Comment: @Keppil, Thanks for your reply. if below line is executed: System.out.println(increaseBy1(new BigDecimal("100.9"))); output will be 101.0. but i am expecting 100.10. Thanks!

Comment: @user1538040: Ok, that was a bit unexpected. Should `100.09` also become `100.10` or `100.010`?

Comment: @Keppil, Sorry. what i want is if 100 is passed it should return 100.01.if 100.01 is passed it should return 100.02....100.10. Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, @user1538040 could you explain the reason for these requirements? They seem quite unusual.

Comment: @user1538040: It doesn't sound like you are using your `BigDecimal` as a number, maybe a `String` representation is more appropriate?

Comment: But from database we get value as BigDecimal type. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't matter what type your database returns, it matters what you want to do with it. Your description does not sound like you are treating them as numbers. For example, you are mostly increasing the number, unless it's something like 100.9 in which case you are reducing it (100.10 < 100.9). It is hard to see how that behaviour makes sense as a number. If you need to treat them as Strings, as @Keppil suggests and as your description suggests, it is easy to convert them to a String

Comment: Thanks for ur solution. i will do the same.